# understanding kafka log.dirs

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, partition, kafka-topic

I have Kafka cluster and the
**log.dirs=/data/kafka** is set to the data directory in server.properties.
my DATA partition is kept getting full due to these logs which take a big part of it.
(talking about binary logs in topic directory like 000000000000000.log)
I read in THE DOCUMENTATION about this parameter
**(log.dirs The directories in which the log data is kept. If not set, the value in log.dir is used)**

and I do not fully understand the meaning yet
Moreover, can they be deleted, and which retention should be configured? and is it recommended to separate it from the data directory?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka Topic is a logical grouping of one or more Kafka partitions. Each kafka partition is essentially (log) file/s on the disk. So the data you published kafka are stored in these files (logs) only.

**log.dirs** tells kafka where to create these files. So whenever you have a new partition (by increasing partition on existing topic or by creating a new topic altogether), you would see new file/s in **log.dirs**.

You should **not** delete the data from this folder manually. Use **log.retention.hours** to configure how long should Kafka hold your data.

Comment: thanks that help, so I have another question in cluster only the leader of a certain partition has new file/s in log.dirs.?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have replication setup, the leader as well as followers will have new files in log.dirs.

Comment: I came here because the default setting is in /tmp, which is obviously wrong for a real configuration, but I wasn't sure whether this setting was just for some ephemeral logs that really should be in /tmp, or for the real data.