# Kafka No space left on device issue

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

[image]

A kafka node stopped working because of `No space left on device`. Error logs are pasted above.

[image]
There are 3 directories specified for the kafka logs.

[image]
But as seen, only 1 directory out of 3 (data01) is full. Rest 2 still have space left on it, with data03 having a large chunk of free space.

In case this helps.
[image]

Comment: Do you have 3 brokers, each with their own directory? You may be sending data that creates a hot partition, thus one directory would increase and the others stay the same. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544003/understanding-kafka-log-dirs).

Comment: There are 9 brokers, each of which has 3 disks of its own.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you likely have hotspots, so some of your partitions are getting more data than others, causing some drives to fill up, while others still have space. When it attempts to write to those partitions on the full drive, it fails and throws the error.

If you want to balance the data across partitions you may need to change your partition assignment strategy, the default is RangeAssignor, but you may want to explore round robin, or sticky assignors.

There are good resources out there to better understand how to choose a partition assignment strategy, including the following:

[Kafka Partition Assignment Strategy](https://www.conduktor.io/blog/kafka-partition-assignment-strategy/)